# Unity and PHPStorm hotkeys conflict

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

I use Ubuntu 13.10 and work in PHPStorm. The problem is that the populat PHPStorm hotkeys don't work but Unity's hotkeys work instead.

For example, by pressing Alt+F1 I'm expecting "Select target" dialog but get the Dash panel selected.

Is there some ways to fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure about [Alt-F1] as this seems to be hard-coded.  What other keys would you like to be re-defined?

Comment: Thanks for the help but I've started to use osx instead of ubuntu..

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
#! /bin/env bash

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings cycle-panels "[]"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings cycle-panels-backward "[]"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-down "['<Shift><Super>Page_Down']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-left "[]"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-right "[]"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-up "['<Shift><Super>Page_Up']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings panel-main-menu "['<Super>s']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications-backward "['<Shift><Super>Tab']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications "['<Super>Tab']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-group-backward "['<Shift><Super>Above_Tab']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-group "['<Super>Above_Tab']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-panels "[]"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-panels-backward "[]"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-down "['<Super>Page_Down']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-left "[]"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-right "[]"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-up "['<Super>Page_Up']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings unmaximize "['<Super>Down']"
```

[Source link](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-55796#comment=27-914143).